# Building a Prime Number Iterable Object in Python

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, iterable

I am trying to learn iterators in Python and as practice, I am trying to build an iterable object which provides prime numbers up to the limit specified.

The idea is that the class can be used to create an object which contains a list of prime number up to the limit given by user.

The logic I am using:

1. The prime numbers are generated sequentially from 2
2. 1 is added to the largest prime in the sequence so far and checked if they are divisible by any of the number in the list of primes so far.
3. If the number is divisible by any one in the prime list, they are discarded and 1 is added to current number to get the next number to try.
4. If they are not divisible by any of the primes in the list so far, they are added to the list as the next prime number.

Following is the code I am working on:

```py
class PrimeList:
    def __init__(self,limit):
        self.val = 2
        self.limit = limit
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.val >= (self.limit**0.5+1):
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return_val = self.val
            while return_val < (self.limit**0.5+1):
                if is_prime(self, return_val+1): # Having problems in this step. Goes into an infinite loop
                    return return_val + 1
                else:
                    return_val +=1
            else:
                return return_val

def is_prime(list_of_primes,x):
    while True:
        try:
            y = next(list_of_primes)
            if x % y == 0:
                return False
        except StopIteration:
            return True

test = PrimeList(100)
print(list(test))
```

The error I get is `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

I guess I don't know how to refer to the iterable object recursively.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're getting - I'm getting a "AttributeError: type object 'PrimeList' has no attribute 'self'"

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to experiment and made code changes which got copied. Have reverted the code. Now it gives error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a disaster!  You're creating an iterator to return primes but internally you're using that same iterator to generate prime divisors to see if the number is prime.  Effectively, exhausting the iterator as it tries to come up with a return value.  Or something like that.  Instead, internally, we need to create a new instance of this iterator (with a smaller limit) to generate the prime divisors.  (I.e. the recursion.)  Something like:

```
class PrimeList:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        self.value = 2

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def is_prime(self, x):
        while True:
            try:
                y = next(self)

                if x % y == 0:
                    return False

            except StopIteration:
                return True

    def __next__(self):

        while self.value < self.limit:
            divisors = PrimeList(int(self.value ** 0.5) + 1)  # recursion

            found = divisors.is_prime(self.value)

            self.value += 1

            if found:
                return self.value - 1

        raise StopIteration()

test = PrimeList(100)
print(*test, sep=", ")
```

This works, but it's got to be on the slow side:

```
% python3 test.py
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
%
```

Cool problem!